# Using an array as a property in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Folks,

I am trying to write a class module in VBA that reads some file names from an Access database so that they can be imported into the same database. I have written several class modules for this database already and they seem to work. However, this module has an array of type `clsImportFile` that I am trying to use as a property. The actual error that exists is

`Run-Time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method`

Here is the `clsFileProcessor` definition:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private pFiles As Variant
Private pIndex As Long
Private pSize As Long

Property Get Files() As Variant
    Files = pFiles
End Property

Property Let Files(f As Variant)
    pFiles = f
End Property

Property Get Index() As Long
    Index = pIndex
End Property

Property Let Index(i As Long)
    pIndex = i
End Property

Property Get Size() As Long
    Size = pSize
End Property

Property Let Size(s As Long)
    pSize = s
End Property

Public Sub Initialize()
    Dim FileArray() As Variant
    ReDim FileArray(Size) As Variant
    Files = FileArray()
End Sub

Public Sub IncrementIndex()
    pIndex = pIndex + 1
End Sub

Public Sub IncrementSize()
    Dim newSize As Integer
    newSize = pSize + 10
    Dim newFiles() As Variant
    ReDim newFiles(newSize) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Index
        newFiles(i) = pFiles(i)
    Next i
    Files = newFiles()
End Sub

Public Sub AddImportHistory(ih As clsImportHistory)
    If Index + 1 = Size Then
        IncrementSize
    Else
        Files(Index) = ih
        IncrementIndex
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the Create sub from my factory:

```
Public Function CreateFileProcessor() As clsFileProcessor
    Set CreateFileProcessor = New clsFileProcessor
    CreateFileProcessor.Index = 0
    CreateFileProcessor.Size = 10
    CreateFileProcessor.Initialize
End Function
```

Finally, here is the test sub:

```
Public Sub TestFileProcessor()
    Dim fp1 As clsFileProcessor
    Set fp1 = CreateFileProcessor()
    Debug.Assert fp1.Index = 0
    Debug.Assert fp1.Size = 10
    Dim ih1 As clsImportHistory
    Set ih1 = CreateImportHistory(i:=3425)
    Dim ih2 As clsImportHistory
    Set ih2 = CreateImportHistory(i:=3426)
    fp1.AddImportHistory (ih1)
    Debug.Assert False
End Sub
```

The line `fp1.AddImportHistory (ih1)` is what is pointed to on the error but I suspect that it has to do with the array.

**EDIT:**
I found by commenting out everything in `clsFileProcessor.AddImportHistory` then systematically un-commenting lines that the issue is with the assignment to the `Files` property. I am `Dimming` the `Files` property as a `Variant`. Is that my issue? I am using the `Variant` type because I am not sure how to define a property that returns or sets an array.

Comment: i'm curious about i:=3425. i haven't seen that before. sry i can't be more help.

Comment: That subroutine has 5 or 6 optional parameters in the signature. You use the:= notation to pass just one of the parameters so that the compiler knows which parameter it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got side tracked for a few days but when I came back to this I figured out that I needed to change

```
fp1.AddImportHistory (ih1)
```

to

```
Call fp1.AddImportHistory (ih1)
```

The trouble is I knew that and just glossed over it.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I checked this, but should `fp1.AddImportHistory (ih1)` be `fp1.AddImportHistory ih1`, without parens?